# Volume of revolution about the line $y = 2$ of region bounded by $x=y^3$ and $y=x^2$

Tags: calculus

I need to find the volume of the solid generated by revolving the region bounded by the graphs of the equations $x=y^3$ and $y=x^2$ about the line $y=2$.

My Attempt: $\pi \int_0^1 (2-x^2)^2-(2-x^{1/3})^2 dx$

Is this set up correct?

Comment: bounded were just added

Comment: You could also use the shell method to get $V=\int_{0}^{1}2\pi(2-y)(\sqrt{y}-y^3)dy$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are correct in your derivation.

A graphical representation of your answer:

[image]